# Editing controllers or models of deployed website without touching database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC website online, i want to know how to update controllers and models without deleting database. When i try to redeploy without deleting database, i get errors. In most cases when i want to edit controllers or models, i would have to delete all files and database then redeploy the website.

Site is going to be used by my clients and they will be storing sensitive information and they will not want to loose it. I would like to know if there way to edit controllers or models without touching database.

Comment: If you modify your entity models, you'll have to update your database accordingly. Either use automatic migrations or script your database upgrades and run those when updating the site. Which scenario applies? What did you do and how do you do migrations?

Comment: I use automatic migration, let say i want to modify one controller, after modifying it i build the solution, how do i apply these changes to remote server?